# Laravel Memcached - Set serializer

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-4, memcached, igbinary

I am using memcached as cache driver in a project based on Laravel 4.2.

I want to set another serializer different from the current one (igbinary) for this project.

How & where can I do that?